# Where can I go?

Tags: discussion

So the rule for questions is:

> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.

I have a question about needing to find resources for a java security related topic, where can I go, without being downvoted into the dirt?

Comment: Either here or on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the question you posted on trying to get hold of java code, that question doesn't really fit here. There are countless places to source weak or vulnerable code on the Internet, but any answer that goes up will become out of date very quickly, as these sort of sites change over time.

If you are trying to research code, or want to discuss security topics, **[The DMZ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz)** can be very welcoming, but the site itself is very focused on questions which will draw out specific answers for that problem - this is the way Stack Exchange works, and while some sites are chattier than others, that rule is quite strict across the entire network.